# android apjsua how call pjsua_app.c from main_android.c function

Tags: android, android-ndk, voip

I am trying to implement apjsua example from pjsip
http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android

I got everything working and I can add main_android.c functions and call them from Java.(JNI is working)problem is I could not figure out how to call pjsip.c library functions from main_android.c

Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: what type of methods did you add in main_android.c? I am also working with apjsua..and now I am struggling to display the client register state (registered, not regstered) on the android side. I don't know how to do this. can u help?